# XPath to match space-separated attribute values?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML:

```
<entities>
  <entity attribute="attribute-value-1 attribute-value-2">value1</entity>
  <entity attribute="attribute-value-5 attribute-value-7 attribute-value-8">value2</entity>
</entities>
```

How can I a select using XPath an entity with attribute value of `"attribute-value-7"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful to avoid inadvertently matching superstrings such as "attribute-value-77" or "wrong-attribute-value-7".

Use the idiom commonly used to match HTML `@class` attributes:

### XPath 1.0

```
//entity[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@attribute), ' '),
                           ' attribute-value-7 ')]
```

### XPath 2.0

```
//entity[tokenize(@attribute,'\s+')='attribute-value-7']
```