# Xpath: Find element with class that contains spaces

Tags: html, xml, xpath

So I have elements that look like this

```
<li class="attribute  "></li> # note the space
<li class="attribute"></li>
```

Using the xpath `//li[@class="attribute"]` will get the second element but not the first. How can I get both elements with the same xpath?

Comment: I believe the issue is similar to what is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925567/xpath-with-regex-match-on-an-attribute-value

Comment: matches seems to solve that issue. However I really need a solution for xpath 1.0.

Comment: For reference, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496151/xpath-to-match-space-separated-attribute-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
//li[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '),
              ' attribute ')]
```

will select all `li` elements with `class` attributes that contain the `attribute` substring, regardless of whether it has leading or trailing spaces.

---

If you only want to match `attribute` with possible leading and trailing spaces only (no other string values), just use `normalize-space()`:

```
//li[normalize-space(@class) = 'attribute']
```

Comment: GOLD! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first expression could be simplified to this too: `//li[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class)), 'attribute')]`

Comment: @Jonathan: The first XPath is really meant to match all of the following cases:  `"attribute"`, `"attribute "`, `"attribute second"`, `"one attribute two"` etc but not `"attributeXYZ"`, for example.