# Syntax error in xpath expression having contains

Tags: xpath

```
List <WebElement> elt2=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains@className,'textInputContainers']"));
```

Also tried the version below:

```
List< WebElement > elt2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains@id,'txt']"));
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no evidence of any effort applied to resolving the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm downvoting. I don't see how you could possibly imagine these expressions are valid XPath. You can't expect to invent random expressions that bear no relationship to XPath syntax and then ask the community what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

`contains()` is a function and so must have `()` around its arguments.

So change

```
//*[contains@className,'textInputContainers']
```

to

```
//*[contains(@className,'textInputContainers')]
```

**Note:** A more robust way to test for a class name within a `@class` attribute can be found here: [Xpath: Find element with class that contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330551/xpath-find-element-with-class-that-contains-spaces)