# XPath - get text from whole document except text from specified elements

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out how to get text using `XPath` and exclude some tags.

Let's say (for illustration) I want to get all text from this page's `body` tag (so all visible text), but I don't want my text to contain text from tags with `class="comment-copy"` i.e. I don't want text to include comments.

I tried this but it doesn't work. It returns text including comments.

```
//body//text()[not(*[contains(@class,"comment-copy")])]
```

Do you have any idea?

**EDIT:**

Probably figured it out but maybe there are better or faster approaches so I won't delete the question.

```
//body//text()[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,"comment-copy")])]
```

Comment: Test comment which shouldn't be in extracted text.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.

Just change

```
//body//text()[not(*[contains(@class,"comment-copy")])]
```

to

```
//body//text()[not(contains(../@class,"comment-copy"))]
```

Note that this will only exclude immediate children `text()` nodes of `comment-copy` marked elements.  Your follow-up XPath will exclude all descendant `text()` nodes beneath `comment-copy` marked elements.

Note: You might want to beef up the robustness of the `@class` test; see [Xpath: Find element with class that contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330551/xpath-find-element-with-class-that-contains-spaces).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes, I want to exclude all text inside the element and it's descendants.